# Java command-line API client to fetch Bitcoin exchange rates

Tags: java, json, api, unit-conversion, cryptocurrency

I am building a simple Java command-line application. And I want to know the best practice and make my code clean. Can anybody suggest to me how many different classes I can make and what more method I need to write to make my code clean? How can I write unit testing for the methods? I am new to writing unit tests.

The question is, I need to call an API then take input from a user and according to the user input I need to call another API, then show some data based on minimum or maximum. I am confused that should I write a separate class for API calls or keep them in the same file. Should I divide my API calling methods more or not? Thanks :)

````
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class BitcoinRateCheckApplicationByCurrency {
    public static final String URL = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";
    public static JSONObject jsonAPIresponseObject = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        jsonAPIresponseObject = getJSONAPIdataFromURL(URL);
        out.println("Input a currency code (USD, EUR, GBP, etc.)");
        ;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String currency = scanner.nextLine();

        JSONObject bpiObject = (JSONObject) jsonAPIresponseObject.get("bpi");

        JSONObject currencyDataObject = (JSONObject) bpiObject.get(currency);

        Double currentRate = (Double) currencyDataObject.get("rate_float");

        Date dNow = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(dNow));

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);
        Date dateBefore30Days = cal.getTime();


        String currentDate = ft.format(dNow);
        String fromDate = ft.format(dateBefore30Days);

        String apiDataRangeURL = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/historical/close.json?start=" + fromDate + "&end=" + currentDate + "&?currency=" + currency;
        JSONObject lastOneMonthDataObject = getJSONAPIdataFromURL(apiDataRangeURL);

        JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) lastOneMonthDataObject.get("bpi");

        Set<String> keySet = obj.keySet();
        ArrayList<Double> priceListForDateRange = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (String x : keySet) {
            double price = (Double) obj.get(x);
            priceListForDateRange.add(price);
        }


        out.println("- The current Bitcoin rate, in the requested currency: " + currentRate);
        out.println("- The lowest Bitcoin rate in the last 30 days, in the requested currency: " + getMinValue(priceListForDateRange));
        out.println("- The highest Bitcoin rate in the last 30 days, in the requested currency: " + getMaxValue(priceListForDateRange));


    }

    public static JSONObject getJSONAPIdataFromURL(String url) throws IOException {

        JSONObject responseJSON = null;
        URL urlForGetRequest = new URL(url);
        String readLine = null;

        HttpURLConnection conection = (HttpURLConnection) urlForGetRequest.openConnection();
        conection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = conection.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((readLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(readLine);
            }
            in.close();
            responseJSON = new JSONObject(response.toString());
        } else {
            System.out.println("GET NOT WORKED");
        }

        return responseJSON;
    }

    public static double getMaxValue(ArrayList<Double> numbers) {

        double maxValue = numbers.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            if (numbers.get(i) > maxValue) {
                maxValue = numbers.get(i);
            }
        }
        return maxValue;
    }

    public static double getMinValue(ArrayList<Double> numbers) {
        double minValue = numbers.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < numbers.size(); i++) {
            if (numbers.get(i) < minValue) {
                minValue = numbers.get(i);
            }
        }
        return minValue;
    }
}

```
````

Answer (score 4):

Before separating the code into classes try separating it into more methods. At the very least separate business/logic code and input/output code. You should be able to use the same, unchanged business code no matter if it's a command line program, has a GUI or is a web application. For example `getJSONAPIdataFromURL` shouldn't write to `System.out`, but return an error value or throw an exception (which you should catch and display to user in the input/output part of the code). That business code would then be a prime example to be put into a separate class.

There are many other things that can be done:

---

> ```
> import java.util.*;
> ```

Don't import using wildcards.

> ```
> import static java.lang.System.out;
> ```

If you import something statically, then use it everywhere and not just in a few places. However I wouldn't statically import `System.out`, since `System.out.println(...)` is more readable than just `out.println(...)`.

---

There is no reason for `jsonAPIresponseObject` to be a (static) field. It's not used anywhere else than in the `main` method, and even if it weren't, then it should be passed around to other methods as an argument.

---

Consider (optionally) allowing the user to pass the currency as a command line argument.

---

`.close()` the `Scanner` and the `InputStream` you get from the `HttpConnection` after you've used it, for example using ["try with resources"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and `.disconnect()` the `HttpConnection`.

Consider using an third party HTTP client library. It maybe a a bit heavy weight for such a small project, but the API is much nicer. (Or Java 9 has a new HTTP client, that is better than the old one).

---

You are neither checking if the `JSONObject::get` calls are throwing an exception nor checking if you safely can cast its results. Use `JSONObject::optJSONObject` (and `JOSNObject::optDouble` for doubles) to get results that don't need casting and check them for null.

---

If you have Java 8, then use the "new" `LocalDate` class to handle dates. It's much simpler than `Date`/`Calendar`:

```
    // The formatter should be a static final field;
    DateTimeFormatter ft = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE;

    LocalDate dNow = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDate dateBefore30Days = dNow.minusDays(30);

    String currentDate = ft.format(dNow);
    String fromDate = ft.format(dateBefore30Days);
```

---

When building an URL make sure that URL parameters are properly escaped, especially since the currency is user input.

---

Use the smallest possible/sensible interface when declaring variables and method signatures. Instead of

```
ArrayList<Double> priceListForDateRange = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

and

```
public static double getMaxValue(ArrayList<Double> numbers) {
```

just

```
List<Double> priceListForDateRange = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
public static double getMaxValue(List<Double> numbers) {
```

---

The min/max methods can be simplified by using Java 8 streams, e.g:

```
public static double getMaxValue(List<Double> numbers) {
   return numbers.stream().max(Comparator.naturalOrder()).get();
}
```

or since you only need the min and max values, calculate them directly in the loop reading them from the JSONObject.

Comment: Many many thanks. I am really grateful for your suggestions. I tried to incorporate all of your suggestions. Here is my code. Any further suggestions if needed would be appreciated. 

https://github.com/forhadmethun/BitcoinRateCheckApplicationByCurrencyJavaCommandLine.git

Comment: @forhadmethun Post a new question with the new code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm just adding some elements to the explanation by RoToRa, use the method [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) of the class `LocalDate` because it outputs the date in ISO-8601 format uuuu-MM-dd, and this is exactly the format you are using. If you are looking for math operations on streams of `Double` like
searching for min, max, average you can use the class [DoubleSummaryStatistics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) like the example below:

```
List<Double> priceListForDateRange;// previously initialized in the code from json values
DoubleSummaryStatistics statistics = priceListForDateRange.stream()
                                        .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
                                        .summaryStatistics();
System.out.println("- The lowest Bitcoin rate in the last 30 days, in the requested currency: " + statistics.getMin());
System.out.println("- The highest Bitcoin rate in the last 30 days, in the requested currency: " + statistics.getMax());
```

Comment: Many many thanks. I am really grateful for your suggestions. I tried to incorporate all of your suggestions. Here is my code. Any further suggestions if needed would be appreciated. 

https://github.com/forhadmethun/BitcoinRateCheckApplicationByCurrencyJavaCommandLine.git

Comment: @forhadmethun You are welcome, once you have modified your code you can post a new question with the new code.